# Need Book Suggestions For Web Applications

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I have an iPhone app out that stores data on the device.  I want to create an app with user accounts like Instagram, Path, Foursquare, Gowalla, etc.

Thus, I think I will need to create an iPhone client app, a MYSQL database, and PHP/Ruby on Rails to connect the two, along with the RestKit Framework for Objective-C.

Are there any good books you guys would recommended for the backend stuff?  I am comfortable with the iOS part, but have no history with the backend/webserver side.

Comment: There are already several questions asking for book recommendations on iPhone programming.  Please check them out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone+books

Comment: http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=learning+php+stackoverflow  http://www.google.co.in/search?num=30&hl=en&newwindow=1&q=learning+ruby+on+rails++stackoverflow&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For learning PHP (I'm assuming you're new to PHP?) I recommend [PHP Solutions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430232498) by David Powers. For Ruby on Rails, check out Ruby on [Rails 3 Tutorial](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321743121) by Michael Hartl.

Comment: Thanks, ill check those out.  Is PHP required for building this type of app? Or can I do iPhone --> RestKit Framework --> MYSQL?

Comment: No, PHP isn't required, it's just another way to implement the server-side of the equation. RestKit isn't sufficient to implement your server-side solution in as far as I understand what RestKit is (not an expert on it.) The server side implementation can be just about anything: PHP, RoR, ASP.NET, etc. that can implement a restful web service if that's the route you're taking.

Comment: Ok thanks.  What would you recommend for the quickest and easiest way to get an app of this nature (social, iPhone) going?  I'm deciding between RoR or PHP still.  Will the final stack come down to: `iPhone --> RestKit --> RoR/PHP --> MYSQL`?

Comment: Well, depending on who you ask you'll get a different opinion with respect to something like that (and I'd probably ask a question like that in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ .) You may want to peruse http://www.amazon.com/Restful-Web-Services-Leonard-Richardson/dp/0596529260/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1308472787&sr=8-1 where the author shows implementations in RoR, Python, and Java.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to answer the second part of your question - yes, your final stack would look like that if you're deciding between PHP and RoR.

Comment: Thanks Knakuta.  If possible, could you just give me a quick rundown of the role of each of those technologies and how they work together within the stack?  I'm having a little trouble understanding how they all play along with each other (except iOS).

Comment: RestKit: allow your iOS application to consume a restful web service.
PHP/RoR: implement the Restful web service - provide an interface for those requesting the service to use, access data from the database through connecting to and querying the db, return data in a format like JSON or XML that the consumer of the restful service can consume.
MySQL: the database or datastore where any data you need to store is kept.
This is a big and incomplete simplification, but it should give you a starting point to investigate further or ask more detailed questions.

Answer (score 1):

Take the [Rails for Zombies online tutorial.](http://railsforzombies.org)

Nothing to setup, just learn and code from your browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to study a new technology, I highly recommend buying a book, and not just try to find some good tutorials online. It will be money well spent esp. if you value your time!

For Rails 3, one of the best books is [Agile Web Development with Rails (4th edition)](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) - you can buy a PDF at pragprog.com for $24, and it's more than enough to get you started quickly.